# How to selectively remove elements from an array in a loop and output back into a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following method that takes a string and returns that string with all the vowels removed. I turn the sting into an array and use a loop to remove the vowels and then convert it back into a string.

```
def disemvowel(string)
  i = 0
  arr = string.split
  arr_new = []
  while i <= string.length
    if arr[i] != ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o"|| "u")
      arr_new << arr[i]
    end
  i +=1
  end
  arr_new.join
end
```

The output doesn't come out the way expected. How could I adjust my current method? Other approaches are welcome.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We need code we can run that demonstrates the problem you've encountered, the minimum input and what you expect the code to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enumerable#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) or [Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) are the idiomatic ways to filter elements out of an array:

```
def disemvowel(string)
  string.split("").reject do |char|
    %w{a e i o u}.include?(char)
  end.join
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much more efficient! Also, still curious to know why the portion of my code above doesn't work as intended, particularly: if arr[i] != ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o"|| "u")

Comment: `("a" || "e" || "i" || "o"|| "u")` evaluates to `true` (because strings are truthy), and therefore you're checking `arr[i] == true` which will always be false. What I think you're _trying_ to do is `arr[i] != "a" && arr[i] != "e" && arr[i] != "i" && arr[i] != "o" && arr[i] != "u"` which is obviously more verbose than something like `%w{a e i o u}.include?(arr[i])`

Comment: Made a couple edits to answer and my above comment, sorry for the sloppiness at first

Comment: Good to know, I substituted your suggested edit above to my original verbose code  (proposed revision containing &&'s) just to test it out; for test cases like  "foobar",  "ruby", "aeiou" it still prints the whole string with vowels. Hmm, not sure what I am still missing?

Comment: Just for clarity, even after I put in the proposed code revision above and it still prints out the full strings with vowels still included: arr[i] != "a" && arr[i] != "e" && arr[i] != "i" && arr[i] != "o" && arr[i] != "u"

Comment: it's because `split()` (without arguments) doesn't actually split out every char, it splits on whitespace. so `"foobar".split == ["foobar"]`. My bad for not realizing this at first. Use `.split("")` or `.chars` (same thing)

Comment: Didn't you recently post an answer that suggested what here would be `"Oh, how now brown cow?".tr("aeiouAEIOU","") #=> "h, hw nw brwn cw?"`?

Comment: Maybe something similar to that, I didn't think of it though